# как можно облегчить этот код ? c# Windows Forms Combobox

Tags: c#

Как можно облегчить этот фрагмент кода чтобы каждый раз не писать try { ... } catch { ... } ?

```
switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start("taskmgr.exe");
            }
                    catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" +
            "\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500");
            }
            break;
                case 1:
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" +
                    "\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start("D:\\Minecraft\\MinecraftLauncher.exe");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" +
                    "\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500");
                    }
                    
                    break;
                case 3:
                    try
                    {
                        Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Арслан\\AppData\\Roaming\\Spotify\\Spotify.exe");
                    }
                    catch { MessageBox.Show("Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" +
                        "\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500"); }


                    break;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: Напишите один раз на верхнем уровне. Ну а вообще т.к. код в кейсах одинаковый, меняется лишь строка, можно использовать коллекции, список или словарь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string error = "Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" + 
"\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500";
string name = Environment.UserName;

try
{
   switch (index)
   {
   case 0: Process.Start("taskmgr.exe"); break;
   case 1: Process.Start("Notepad.exe"); break;
   case 2: Process.Start(@"D:\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"); break;
   case 3: Process.Start($@"C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"); break;
   default: break;
   }
}
catch { MessageBox.Show(error); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы и нет... (улучшенная версия)

```
    private string _messageError = "Программа не найдена по указанному пути в коде" +
                "\nПопробуйте связаться с автором программы Master pro 1322#5500";
    public string GetPathByIndex(int index) =>
    index switch
    {
        1 => "taskmgr.exe",
        2 => "Notepad.exe",
        3 => @"D:\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe",
        _ => "none"
    };

    public void StartBuIndex(int index)
    {
        var path = GetPathByIndex(index);
        if (File.Exists(path))
            Process.Start(path);
        else
            MessageBox.Show(_messageError);
    }
```